# Control mouse movement with Protractor

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, protractor, angular-test

In a particular scenario I have to get full control of my mouse and with the `actions()` class I'm not able to do it.

In my application there is a map and there is a functionality, which uses lasso to select certain portion of the map (say we draw a circle with lasso and selection is represented by a red circle), then only a pop up comes for further navigation, but when I use actions class like below

```
var loc = element(by.xpath("//span[@id='imgLasso']"));
browser.actions()
    .mouseMove(loc, {x: 550, y: 436}) 
    .mouseDown()
    .mouseMove({x: 700, y: 236})
    .perform();
```

actual mouse movement doesn't occur and I found no solution, except using Java robot class, hence I want to create a batch file, which calls a Java class with robot methods in it, but I'm not sure how to do it.

---

UPDATE

```
it("working with lasso",function() {
    browser.sleep(5000);
    element(by.xpath("//span[@id='imgLasso']")).click();
    var plot0 = element(by.xpath("//span[@id='imgLasso']"));
    browser.sleep(2000); // intentional wait
    browser.actions()
        .mouseMove({x: 100, y: 100})
        .mouseDown()
        .mouseMove({x: 400, y: 0})
        .perform();

    browser.sleep(8000);
    element(by.xpath("//*[@id='imputTerritory']")).sendKeys("NewTeritory");
});
```

on execution of the code above, here are my observations:

1. Till `var plot0` line, code is executed normally.
2. After that `browser.action()...` get executed only just before Chrome is closed by protractor. Don't know why. (also I have included sleep to verify that)
3. Also just before Chrome is closed I can see a straight red line on the map, but not followed by any pop up (it's possible the mouse is not released by actions class)

Just to add this time I'm not passing any `plot0` element in the code, I'm just keeping my mouse pointer on the map manually, just before above spec is executed.

Comment: Have you tried `browser.actions().dragAndDrop(...).perform()`?

Comment: @ alecxe i tried browser.actions().dragAndDrop(plot0,{x: 400, y: 500}).perform(); but no help but when i do like this browser.actions()
       .mouseMove(plot0, {x: 100, y: 100})
       .mouseDown()
       .mouseMove({x: 400, y: 0})
       .perform(); here are my observations 1.above code executes just before chrome is closed by protractor 2.above code works as i can see a red straight line which blinks just before chrome is closed but no pop up window get opens (functionality of app on draw of line,circle or sth).is it possible above code do not release mouse.

Comment: Yes, you need a command to release the mouse button in your chain

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing `mouseUp` event in your chain